# How to make a MATLAB plot interactive?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a simple interface for plotting quadratic Lagrange polynomials. For this, you need just 3 points (with each their own x,y,z coordinates), which are then interpolated using the quadratic Lagrange polynomials.

It's easy to make a static version, or even one that lets the user input the 3 points before plotting the curve. But it should also be possible for the user to drag an existing point in the plot window to another position, and then re-plot the curve automatically using the new position of this point!

[image]

So in short, the user should be able to drag these black dots to another location. After that (or while dragging), the curve should be updated.

```
function Interact()

% Interactive stuff here

figure();
hold on;
axis([0 7 0 5])

DrawLagrange([1,1; 3,4; 6,2])

function DrawLagrange(P)

plot(P(:,1), P(:,2), 'ko--', 'MarkerSize', 10, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'k')

t = 0:.1:2;
Lagrange = [.5*t.^2 - 1.5*t + 1; -t.^2 + 2*t; .5*t.^2 - .5*t];

CurveX = P(1,1)*Lagrange(1,:) + P(2,1)*Lagrange(2,:) + P(3,1)*Lagrange(3,:);
CurveY = P(1,2)*Lagrange(1,:) + P(2,2)*Lagrange(2,:) + P(3,2)*Lagrange(3,:);

plot(CurveX, CurveY);
```

I think I either have to use functions like **WindowButtonDownFcn**, **WindowButtonUpFcn** and **WindowButtonMotionFcn**, or the **ImPoint** from the Image Processing Toolbox. But how?

[Edit]
It should also work in 3D, since I'd like to generalize this concept to tensor product surfaces.

Comment: did you ever try solving this with linkdata?

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I searched for some more information on the **ImPoint** option from the Image Processing Toolbox, and wrote this script.

Since **ImPoint** only works for a 2D setting (and I'd like to generalize this to 3D to be able to work with surfaces instead of curves), it is not really an acceptable answer! But somebody might benefit from it, or get an idea how to do this in 3D.

```
% -------------------------------------------------
% This file needs the Image Processing Toolbox!
% -------------------------------------------------

function Interact(Pos)

% This part is executed when you run it for the first time.
% In that case, the number of input arguments (nargin) == 0.
if nargin == 0

    close all;
    clear all;
    clc;

    figure();
    hold on;
    axis([0 7 0 5])

    % I do not know how to do this without global variables?
    global P0 P1 P2

    % GCA = Get handle for Current Axis
    P0 = ImPoint(gca,1,1);
    setString(P0,'P0');
    P1 = ImPoint(gca,2,4);
    setString(P1,'P1');
    P2 = ImPoint(gca,6,2);
    setString(P2,'P2');

    % Call subfunction
    DrawLagrange(P0,P1,P2)

    % Add callback to each point
    addNewPositionCallback(P0,@Interact);
    addNewPositionCallback(P1,@Interact);
    addNewPositionCallback(P2,@Interact);

else

    % If there _is_ some input argument, it has to be the updated
    % position of a moved point.
    global H1 H2 P0 P1 P2

    % Display X and Y coordinates of moved point
    Pos

    % Important: remove old plots! Otherwise the graph will get messy.
    delete(H1)
    delete(H2)
    DrawLagrange(P0,P1,P2)

end

function DrawLagrange(P0,P1,P2)

P = zeros(3,2);
% Get X and Y coordinates for the 3 points.
P(1,:) = getPosition(P0);
P(2,:) = getPosition(P1);
P(3,:) = getPosition(P2);

global H1 H2
H1 = plot(P(:,1), P(:,2), 'ko--', 'MarkerSize', 12);

t = 0:.1:2;
Lagrange = [.5*t.^2 - 1.5*t + 1; -t.^2 + 2*t; .5*t.^2 - .5*t];

CurveX = P(1,1)*Lagrange(1,:) + P(2,1)*Lagrange(2,:) + P(3,1)*Lagrange(3,:);
CurveY = P(1,2)*Lagrange(1,:) + P(2,2)*Lagrange(2,:) + P(3,2)*Lagrange(3,:);

H2 = plot(CurveX, CurveY);
```

I added some comments for clarity.

**[Edit]** In the preview the syntax highlighting doesn't look very good! Should I define the language to be highlighted somewhere?

Comment: So to test this script, save it as **Interact.m** and invoke it _without_ input arguments.

Answer (score 6):

A better solution (one that does not need any additional toolboxes) is to use events. First step:

```
H = figure('NumberTitle', 'off');
set(H, 'Renderer', 'OpenGL');

set(H, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', @MouseClick);
set(H, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @MouseMove);
set(H, 'WindowScrollWheelFcn', @MouseScroll);
set(H, 'KeyPressFcn', @KeyPress )
```

The next step is to define the functions like `MouseClick`, this is the place where you implement how to react to events (e.g. mouse buttons being clicked, keys being pressed).

In the meantime I implemented an interactive B-spline environment in MATLAB, the source code (along with a concise manual) can be downloaded from https://github.com/pjbarendrecht/BsplineLab.

Comment: the link does not exists anymore!

Comment: @Arash You're right, my old university removed the page a couple of weeks ago. I might create a GitHub page for an improved version or write something similar for Geogebra :)

Comment: Thanks,but How Can drag nodes in it?

Comment: @Arash Right click to select and then press `G` to grab the node and move it (left click again to release the node). It's based on Blender's workflow (http://www.blender.org/). See also the accompanying PDF.

Answer (score 3):

Great question!  I've had this problem too and wondered how to solve it before, but never looked into it.  My first thought was to use `ginput` and then minimize the distance to the line and find the closest point.  I thought that was a bit of a hack so I looked around.  Seems like that's the only reasonable answer out there and was confirmed [here with this code as an example.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25417-ginput-and-plot-data)

```
%minimum absolute differences kick in again
xx = 1:10; %xdata
yy = exp(xx);

plot(xx,yy);
[xm ym] = ginput(1); %xmouse, ymouse

%Engine
[~, xidx] = min(abs(xx-xm)); %closest index
[~, yidx] = min(abs(yy-ym));
x_closest = xx(xidx) %extract
y_closest = yy(yidx)
```

Not sure how it scales to 3D, but I thought this would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the option _ginput_! However, it's not possible to drag a point, or is it? Just searched for more infomation/examples on **ImPoint** and wrote a simple script. I'll post this as an answer, but I won't accept my own answer since it doesn't work for 3D. But perhaps some people will find it useful.